# Meaning of zeros in the column best bound in docplex?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, docplex

[image]I am trying to solve a large-scale MIP problem in docplex(python). I give to the model a MIP start solution, I remark that after 20 hours, the best integer still the cost of the MIP start and the best bound is fix to zero. There is any explanation to zeros in the best bound ??[image]

Comment: Is this by any chance a "big M" type model?

Comment: Yeah , but i turned it to indicator constraints

Comment: @Nada.M, have you tried to solve the model without the use of MIP-Start? If so, was there any best bound reported by the solver?

Comment: Yeah, I tried for other instances of data and it was more time-consuming. So I used the MIP Start, And the instances were solved to optimality ( and for an instance large than the one specified in the picture, it found 28 feasible solutions with a gap of 30%). I want just an explanation of the zeros if it is possible that the cause id the MIP-Start (the MIP start is a solution of a construction heuristic that has been improved by a metaheuristic).

Comment: I don't think you can determine why the bound is not moving just by looking at the log file. Regarding the "big M" constraints, I think even when you enter them as indicators it is still possible for "leakage" to occur (because CPLEX may turn them into big M constraints). Can you find tight values for the Ms?

Comment: Yes, I found tight values for the M's in the first tests, but that led to infeasible solutions in most cases. it seems that these values even if based on a good study limit the search space